# Google Tag Manager trigger based on changed variable in datalayer

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have a variable `watchedVariable` that can either be "ABC" or "DEF" and a tag that should fire every time the value of `watchedVariable` changes from "ABC" to "DEF" or vice versa.

I tried to write a JavaScript that pushes e.g. `"event" : "watchedVariable changed"` based on an older [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453957/can-i-watch-for-changes-to-datalayer-variables-in-google-tag-manager) I found, but I can't apply it to my use case.

I adjusted the name of `{{watchedVariable}}` and the `dataLayer.push` command at the end. Is there more to adjust?

**JS Code snippet**

```
<script>
var someEventIsTriggered = function(e) {
    var target = $('input#watched');
    var lastEvent = dataLayer
                        .filter(function (e) { return e.event === 'gtm.customEvent'; })
                        .pop();
    var lastValue = lastEvent instanceof Object 
                        ? lastEvent[{{watchedVariable}}] 
                        : false;

    // Trigger a generic "gtm.click" event on every click
    dataLayer.push({
        "event": "gtm.customEvent",
        {{watchedVariable}}: target.val()
    });

    if (lastValue !== target.val()) {
        dataLayer.push({
        "event": "watchedVariable changed"
    });
    }

};
</script>
```

Comment: not a best choice. Can we know when the value is ABC and if user perform something and it will become DEF. We might need another way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The variable can store the following values:
`"on|on"` --> functional + marketing cookies accepted
`"on|off"` --> functional accepted, marketing opt-out
`"off|on"` --> functional opt-out, marketing accepted
`"off|off"` --> all cookies denied

The variable changes if
a) the marketing and/or functional cookie is switched off via toggle or
b) a form is submitted

It does not change directly, but if a new page is loaded.
This is why normal triggers do not help me here, since I can't trigger on form submission or toggle interaction.